# my routes dont work so i cant acces a product page

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes, slim

I got a new obstacle.
I did make a route for a specific "Product" page and dont work.

Here's my routes code

`$app->get('/products{slug}',['Cart\Controllers\ProductController','get'])->setName('product.get');`

and my .htaccess code is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

And when I access the page " localhost/cart/products/am1" it gets me Page Not Found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code to show single product

```
$app->get('/products/{slug}', "ProductController@getSingleProduct");
```

take cake there is "/" before parameter slug

Comment: `ClassName@methodName` is not the correct syntax. It should be `Cart\Controllers\ProductController::class . ':get'`